# EF inserting duplicate row even when parent is attached

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My entities:

**UserProfile:** 
- Nothing of importance here.

**SupportTicket:**
 - UserProfile

**SupportTicketMessage:**
 - UserProfile
 - SupportTicket

My issue is that whenever I try to insert a SupportTicketMessage I get an additional UserProfile inserted into the database (a duplicate) even though I've attached the corresponding SupportTicket.

Here's my code (inside the SupportTicket class, so *this* means SupportTicket):

```
public void AddReply(UserProfile user)
{
    SupportTicketMessage msg = new SupportTicketMessage(user, this);
    using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.SupportTickets.Attach(msg.Ticket);
        db.SupportTicketMessages.Add(msg);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Whenever I run this the SupportTicketMessage gets inserted just fine but it inserts a duplicate UserProfile even though there's a matching one already.

What's the problem here?

Btw here's the supportticketmessage constructor:

```
   public SupportTicketMessage(UserProfile author, SupportTicket ticket)
    {
        Author = author;
        Ticket = ticket;
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: Anyone can help me? It's really bugging me!

Comment: Have a look at this question, they address this issue and provide three solutions for the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416323/insert-new-object-with-existing-object

Comment: Here is another one that may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884887/prevent-entity-framework-to-insert-values-for-navigational-properties

Comment: Can you show the code of the `SupportTicketMessage` constructor?

Comment: @Slauma
Sure I've added it to the post. It's really basic though.

Answer (score 1):

> I get an additional UserProfile inserted into the database (a
>   duplicate) even though I've attached the corresponding SupportTicket.

Yes, you attached the corresponding `SupportTicket` with `Attach(msg.Ticket)`, but where did you attach the `UserProfile` that's actually the duplicated entity? If `msg.Ticket.UserProfile` is already set to the profile you pass into `AddReply` then the duplication is unexpected. But it's not visible in your code snippets that `msg.Ticket.UserProfile` is set. If it's not set you need to attach the `msg.UserProfile` as well:

```
db.UserProfiles.Attach(msg.Author);
db.SupportTickets.Attach(msg.Ticket);
db.SupportTicketMessages.Add(msg);
db.SaveChanges();
```